# "Old wild west" secret sauce

Tags: sauce, food-identification

I don't know if the "Old Wild West" franchise even exists outside of Italy, but I'll give it a shot anyway.
In those restaurants they serve [this sauce](http://s3.amazonaws.com/foodspotting-ec2/reviews/1640149/thumb_600.jpg?1335267215),

[image: sauce]

which colors resembles much the one of a [cocktail sauce](http://www.alimentis.it/public/images/2662.jpg). In the sauce there is something solid that I believe to be tiny pieces of chili peppers.
It has a neutral smell and tastes creamy, slightly spicy. It is very good to eat with sausages or roasted meat.

I have asked the waiters to tell me the recipe, but they wouldn't. Once, a friend of mine told me that it was a mix of mayo, ketchup, chili peppers and worchester sauce. I tried several times to mix them with verious percentages of the components and nothing I could come up with tasted anything like that.

Can you help me to understand the recipe?

Comment: Tiny pieces of chili wouldn't taste creamy. There can be spicy "tiny pieces" or a spicy "cream", but I've never come across "tiny creamed pieces". My personal opinion: It must be one hell of a sauce, because the rest on that plate doesn't look like anything to get excited about.

Comment: As you can see, in the sauce there are some "irregularities", but you can't feel them in your mouth. Yes, those are "tiny spicy bits", but the texture of the whole sauce is actually "creamy".
Well, in my opinion it IS a hell of a sauce.

Comment: It looks suspiciously like "Thousand Island" Dressing from the US.

Comment: A few possibilities, based on your description : (1) mayo + sambal (and maybe some worcestershire sauce)  (2) Thousand island + ground cayenne or chili powder.  (3) Thousand island made w/ minced pickled jalapeños instead of standard pickle relish.

Comment: Even though I've never eaten sambal, this sauce looks to me to be pretty tasty, maybe strong in flavour, while the sauce I posted is quite "smooth" and "soft". I will try thousand island and let you know

Comment: It wasn't absolutely the thousand island :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

I brought some OWW sauce back with me from Italy this summer. Here are a list of ingredients on the back of the packet in both Italian and French.

> ingredients: Sunflower oil, water, vinegar, sugar, pureed tomatoes, egg yolk, iodized salt, mustard, modified starch, salt, dried parsley, spice extracts (paprika, turmeric), smoked paprika powder, thickener (xanthane), powdered cayenne pepper, smoke aroma, natural lemon aroma

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice.  Where is the english part?

Comment: Hi Annika, thank you for this find, it's great. We like our answers being findable with our search, so typed text is better than an image. I typed off an English translation.

Comment: So mayo, ketchup , mustard and chipotle powder should approximate this :)

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean : and parsley.  (I suspect the tumeric is more for color than flavor, and that you're replacing the paprika, smoked paprika, cayenne, and smoke aroma with the chipotle).  I'd be even lazier, and mix mayo with the sauce from a can of chipotles en adobo.  If it needed more sweetness, then I'd add the ketchup.

Answer (score 10):

I've never been to Old Wild West but that looks very much like "fry sauce" or "secret sauce" as we use them here in the United States. In looking at Old Wild West's website, it appears to be geared around offering traditional US style burgers, fries, steaks, ribs, etc. so the inclusion of US style fry sauce would make sense. Here is a link to a typical version that would be used here: http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/epicurious-not-so-secret-sauce-51261820

Comment: That is right, the old wild west is a tex-mex styl-ish fast food restaurant. Can I substitute the "spicy pickle juice" with anything else? I don't know if I can find anything like that to buy here

Comment: Is it pickles in general that aren't available, or just "spicy pickles"? If you have access to dill pickles, etc, then you can use that. Otherwise you could substitute a splash a vinegar (cider or white) and if desired add a pinch of pickling spices (pepper, dill, etc). You could also leave it out altogether.

Comment: That's it! I tried it and it tasted absolutely-ish like the one in the picture. I have to figure out the perfect quantities, but it's this one

Comment: @Noldor130884 I know I'm late to this party, but sometimes "spicy pickles" are called "zesty pickles". https://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/eb471bb1-d16a-451e-86a2-28021ec9cbfe_1.3887dae6bc7a5f93db20060f415040c6.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF